# Laravel Job Batching unable to cancel

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have a simple laravel job batching, my problem is when one of my queue inside batch is failed and throw an exception, it doesn't stop or cancel the execution of the batch even I add the cancel method, still processing the next queue.

this is my handle and failed method

```
public function handle()
{
    if ($this->batch()->cancelled()) {
        return;
    }
    
    $csv_data = array_map('str_getcsv', file($this->chunk_directory));
    foreach ($csv_data as $key => $row) {
        if(count($this->header) != count($row)) {
            $data = array_combine($this->header, $row);
        } else {
            $this->batch()->cancel();
            throw new Exception("Your file doesn't match the number of headers like your product header");
        }
    }

}

public function failed(\Exception $e = null)
{
    broadcast(new QueueProcessing("failed", BatchHelpers::getBatch($this->batch()->id)));
}
```

here is my commandline result

```
[2021-01-11 01:17:57][637] Processing: App\Jobs\ImportItemFile
[2021-01-11 01:17:57][637] Failed:     App\Jobs\ImportItemFile
[2021-01-11 01:17:58][638] Processing: App\Jobs\ImportItemFile
[2021-01-11 01:17:58][638] Processed:  App\Jobs\ImportItemFile
```

Comment: I am not familiar with batching but I suggest you try not throwing an exception after the batch is cancelled in case cancelling  happens at job termination

Comment: Or maybe I put the thrown exception before cancelling the batch, I did that to record the queue exception so that I can show every queue failed description on the dashboard, but still the same

Answer (score 2):

From the [Laravel 8 Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#allowing-failures) documentation:

> When a job within a batch fails, Laravel will automatically mark the batch as "cancelled"

So the default behavior is that the whole batch is marked as "canceled" and stops executing (note that the currently executing jobs will not be stopped).
In your case if the batch execution is continuing, maybe you've turned on the `allowFailures()` option when created a batch?

By the way you don't need to call the `cancel()` method. When an exception is thrown, the given job is already "failed" and the whole batch cancels.
Either remove the `cancel()` line, or `return` after the cancelation method (without throwing an exception). (see [Cancelling batches](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#cancelling-batches))